# On a challenging Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

In my calculation, I derived that
$$
|\frac{e}{e-1}(e^z-1)|\leq \frac{1}{2}  e^{\delta|z|}‎ +‎\frac{12-\pi^2}{12\delta} (e^{\delta|z|}-1)+\frac{\pi^3}{12 (\pi^2-\delta^2)}\sinh(\pi |z|)  \\‎
+\frac{\pi^2 \delta}{12 (\pi^2-\delta^2)}(\cosh(\pi|z|)-1)‎,
$$  holds when $\delta=1$, for $z \in C.$
Now I want to know what about  $\delta= \frac{1}{2}$? It means what happened if  $\delta= \frac{1}{2}$?
$$
|\frac{e}{e-1}(e^z-1)|\leq \frac{1}{2}  e^{\frac{|z|}{2}}‎ +‎\frac{12-\pi^2}{6} (e^{\frac{|z|}{2}}-1)+\frac{\pi^3}{12 (\pi^2-\frac{1}{4})}\sinh(\pi |z|)  \\‎
+\frac{\pi^2 }{24 (\pi^2-\frac{1}{4})}(\cosh(\pi|z|)-1).
$$
Does it hold for $z \in C$?
Would you please help me? Thanks.